# Creating a descendant of another class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, serialization

I want to create a new class based off the following:

```
    [Serializable()]
    public class Class_A : ISerializable
    {
        public int DISP_SEGS { get; set; }

        //Default constructor
        public Class_A()
        {
            //
        }

        //Deserialization constructor
    //If I add virtual to this I get an error
        public Class_A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo PI in this.GetType().GetProperties()) PI.SetValue(this, info.GetValue(PI.Name, PI.PropertyType));
        }

        //Serialization function
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo PI in this.GetType().GetProperties()) info.AddValue(PI.Name, PI.GetValue(this));
        }
    }
```

I want "Class_B" to use the functionality of Serialization & De-Serialization functions.  Don't want to create a whole new class and duplicate all the code, which will be in the base.  I want to be able to just create a Class_B object and later call:

```
    Class_B cb = new Class_B();
```

...

```
    bformatter.Serialize(stream, cb);
```

...

```
    cb = (Class_B)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is *almost always* a bad idea; I strongly advise against it. This rarely ends well... (sorry if this seems dismissive, but I've answered *so very many* serialization questions based on people using `BinaryFormatter` when it is just going to bite them, and then: has bitten them)

Comment: I need a binary formatted output file.

Comment: "binary formatted" is not the same as "using BinaryFormatter" - there are a good number of serializers that deal in binary (protobuf, msgpack, etc) - none of which will hurt you in the ways that BinaryFormatter will; they'll almost always be faster and have smaller output, too.

Comment: Ya, I saw a few of those. I'm serializing text and images together.  I agree, with you.  Problem is I don't really want to use third-party libraries.  Unless, I can cut & paste a few functions into a class file.  I may "opensource " this stuff later and don't want to make a person download extra stuff.  I'd distribute the library with it.  But, I'd feel better pointing a person to said third-party website.  I'd like to be able to hand it over to anyone with VS installed and have them just open and compile.  Stock code, from Microsoft.

Comment: reality is that build doesn't work like that any more; most of the time you're taking a pile of `<PackageReference>` entries from nuget, which might be nuget, but could be 3rd party without it being different in any way (from the consumer's perspective)

Comment: I just tried switching to Protobuf. Not working,  It doesn't seem to do images or image arrays  Looking online apparently it doesn't like other types either.  This is why I don't like third -party stuff.  Microsofts serializer just works.  I'll keep trying to get it.

Comment: Protobuf works just fine with `byte[]`. "Just works" is very misleading - most types are not `[Serializable]` and won't work with `BinaryFormatter`. It is up to you, of course, but : I am extensively experienced in serialization, and I have seen more people hit more pain with `BinaryFormatter` than any other choice.

Comment: So ... I need to convert my image[] into a byte[] during serialization and de-serialization?  K.  :( I really appreciate everyones input. Your guys have been great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm converting:

```
    //My base class
    [ProtoContract]
    public class grid
    {
        [ProtoMember(1), CategoryAttribute("Grid Settings"), DescriptionAttribute("Number of Horizontal GRID Segments.")]
        public int HorizontalCells { get; set; }

        //more properties
    }

    //Our Protostub ... Originally, just for Stackoverflow.  But, I'm liking the name.
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(7, typeof(SKA_Segments))]
    public class ProtoStub : grid
    {
    }

    SKA_Segments seg_map;

    [ProtoContract]
    public class SKA_Segments : ProtoStub
    {
        public SKA_Segments()
        {
        }

        public override void Draw(Graphics Graf, Pen pencil)
        {
            base.Draw(Graf, pencil);
        }
    }

    //Serialization stuff
    seg_map.HorizontalCells = 1000;  //test property comes from the grid class

    //Need to stream all three of these into the one file
    //Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, map, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
    //Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, col_map, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
    Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, seg_map, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);

    //De-Serialization stuff
    //map = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<SKA_MAP>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
    //col_map = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<SKA_Collision>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
    seg_map = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<SKA_Segments>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
```

Comment: Oh man, I think I got it working.  I have to adjust some stuff.  Bummer, I need to go all the way back to the grid class and add the ProtoInclude() lines.  That makes this class project specific.  This was going to be a generic class.  I know, how hard is it to copy the file over to your new project and delete or change the lines.  Ya, but still ...

Answer (score 1):

As advised, I switched from the Binaryformatter to Protobuf.  After, a few issues, I've gotten it working.  So, I'm back to my original question in a new format.

I have a base class and want to create a few different classes off it.  I seen, you're suppose to use Protobufs ProtoInclude attribute.  But, it seems backward.  It says, my base class has to know about the derived types.

```
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(7, typeof(SomeDerivedType))]
    class SomeBaseType {...}

    [ProtoContract]
    class SomeDerivedType {...}
```

This is a stand-alone class I'm deriving from.  So, it needs to be generic.

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public class grid
    {
    }
```

So, I need to derive, from it.

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public class Class_A : grid
    {
    }  

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Class_B : grid
    {
    }
```

Putting ProtoInclude on Class_A & Class_B doesn't do anything, I understand.  Not, if it needs to be on the grid class.  What's the best way to do this?  As, I'm typing I'm wondering if I need to make a stub class that knows about Class_A & Class_B?

```
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(7, typeof(Class_A))]
    [ProtoInclude(8, typeof(Class_B))]
    public class ProtoStub : grid
    {
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Class_A : ProtoStub
    {
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Class_B : ProtoStub
    {
    }
```

If that works, alright. :( But, that's just extra unnecessary code and it makes me sad.

Comment: Serialization & Deserialization not working.  Well not sure about the Serialization.  Only the class, which is on it's own works.  It's the class that inherits from it which doesn't work.  The base class has fields in it, which I set in the inherited one and nothing seems to get set.  So childclass.INHERITED_PROPERTY = WHATEVER, I serialize, I deserialize and nothing.

Comment: I've tried to answer the text in the actual post here; I'll have a look at the *comment* in a little bit...

Comment: added example re the comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm really answering [*your answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50282225/23354) here, not the question, but:

Yes, protobuf-net models inheritance via the parent type. This is actually pretty common in serialization; see also `XmlIncludeAttribute` (`XmlSerializer`) and `KnownTypeAttribute` (`DataContractSerializer`). The reason for this is that these serializers *don't include the full type metadata into the stream*. This is actually a good thing: it means you can change your model or rename your assemblies etc and as long as you still meet the serialization contract: it won't matter. When you think of *serialization*: yes, it sounds trivial to check the parent types etc, but: for **deserialization** to work correctly from a polymorphism / LSP standpoint, it needs to be possible to deserialize **knowing only the base type**.

So: to take your example: if all you knew was `ProtoStub`, and you saw a "field 7" on the wire, what would you do next? Would you scan all types in the current assembly for something that looks like a candidate? What about types in *other* assemblies? (there's no requirement that only one assembly is involved in the model). It becomes a very complex task to resolve the sub-types in that scenario.

But: protobuf-net acknowledges that in the multi-assembly you might not have a reference in that direction, so the type can also be specified as a fully-qualified type name as a string, or the entire inheritance model can be configured at runtime via the `RuntimeTypeModel` API if you prefer. The same is true for some other serializers - for example, `XmlSerializer` has `XmlAttributeOverrides` for configuring the model at runtime in a very similar way.

Specifically in the case of protobuf (and protobuf-net), there's one *additional* reason to prefer decorating the parent type: the field rules. Field numbers (the `7` in `[ProtoInclude(7, ...)]`, or the 3 in `[ProtoMember(3)]`) are required to be unique *for that type*, so being able to see the field numbers in use all in one place, rather than needing to look at `Class_A` / `Class_B` to see which fields are in use, is very handy. This is because in protobuf terms, the model shown in your example is essentially (in protobuf terms):

```
message ProtoStub {
  // other fields of ProtoStub here

  oneof subtype {
     Class_A a  = 7;
     Class_B b  = 8;
  }
}
message Class_A {}
message Class_B {}
```

which is *essentially* the same as:

```
message ProtoStub {
  // other fields of ProtoStub here

  optional Class_A a  = 7; // note: at most one of
  optional Class_B b  = 8; // 7/8 will be specified
}
message Class_A {}
message Class_B {}
```

meaning: the root type *contains* the sub-types. This seems to surprise most people, who expect the sub-types to contain the parent type, i.e.

```
message ProtoStub {}
message Class_A {
  // other Class_A fields
  ProtoStub parent = 42;
}
message Class_B {
  // other Class_A fields
  ProtoStub parent = 42;
}
```

but that layout would make it completely impossible to deserialize when all you know is the root type - how would you know which type you're starting from?

So: that's why it works that way; the logic here can be applied to pretty much every serializer that doesn't embed full type information into the output.

---

Re the "not working" comment; the most common "not working" thing here is simply not rewinding a `MemoryStream` between write and read; I wonder if that is what happened in this case. Here's a working example:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.IO;

public abstract class grid { }

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(7, typeof(Class_A))]
[ProtoInclude(8, typeof(Class_B))]
public class ProtoStub : grid
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int RootMember { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Class_A : ProtoStub
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string DerivedMember { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Class_B : ProtoStub
{
}
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ProtoStub obj = new Class_A
        {
            RootMember = 123,
            DerivedMember = "abc"
        }, clone;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;
            clone = Serializer.Deserialize<ProtoStub>(ms);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(clone.RootMember);
        if(clone is Class_A)
        {
            Class_A typed = (Class_A)clone;
            Console.WriteLine(typed.DerivedMember);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting ... Looking at it now.  Below is my starting point.